# checking multiple condition in ng-if

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, ng-show, angular-ng-if

I need to check 4 conditions in ng-if which are boolean conditions. If any of them is true, I need to display some div.

Is there any simple and better way to do it please?

```
<div ng-if="ctrl.survivor || ctrl.doctor || ctrl.patient || ctrl.beneficiary">
<div ng-bind-html=" {{ myContent }}">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you could put the logic inside a function in the controller, but there isn't a simpler way to represent this logic; the function will essentially look the same.

Comment: @Claies: Thank you, so is this the correct syntax? I am new to ANgular. I am yet to test this code though. I will do it now. But is this all looking good? And yes, I get the setup for this in controller only

Comment: Agree with @Claies, Also, what are other types of user roles besides those four mentioned above? You could potentially simply the logic by using the idea of Not if.

Comment: 2 things: **1st:** The syntax of `ng-if` is correct.. I don't know how is your structure, but let's suppose you have 5 kinds [survivor, doctor, patient, beneficiary, anyone], so you could simply use `ng-hide="ctrl.anyone"` instead of `ng-if` (so that will only be hidden when it's *anyone*, note the reduce). The **2nd.** thing is with `ng-bind-html`, it's incorrect, you should write simply `ng-bind-html="myContent"` (without interpolation `{}`).

Comment: @IsabelHM: nothing else apart from the logic above, also, can I use ng-show if that's better than ng-if? Secondly, as you said not, its a ood idea, but how to write the syntax :S

Comment: @developer033: Thank you, I did similar to what you said, it works :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

In general, complex logic inside of angular expressions is a code smell:

- hard to read
- hard to debug
- hard to test

In general, I try to avoid boolean logic or anything else that indicates complexity in angular expressions that I write or code review. Instead, I recommend that you extract the logic into a controller method and call the controller method directly. This allows you to also write a nice unit test for it. The final code that I would recommend would look something like this:

```
<div ng-if="ctrl.isApplicable()">
  <div ng-bind-html=" {{ myContent }}"></div>
</div>
```

In the controller:

```
class Ctrl {
  ...    
  isApplicable() {
    return survivor || ctrl.doctor || ctrl.patient || ctrl.beneficiary;
  }
  ...
}
```